# How to get the last chars of a string that ends with a new line (\n) in PHP?

Tags: php, substring, line-breaks

I need to check if a submitted string ends in, let's say a few periods followed by a new line. How can I check for that?

Example:

`substr($_POST['text'], -5) == "...\n"`

(not sure if mb_substr would work better, nor how to state the \n within the string... hypothetically \n is counted as 2 chars just for the example)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `\n` is a single char. Perhaps you have `\r\n` in mind? I think the issue is that you're looking at some rendered output and you don't really know if it's `\n`, `\r\n` or `<br>`. You may use `bin2hex()` to find the exact bytes.

Comment: thank you, I'll look into bin2hex()

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález it was it! it was actually a ```\r\n``` thank you for the insight!

Answer (score 0):

```
$org = "this is just a test...\n";

if (substr($org, -4) == "...\n") {
  echo "Yes\n";
{
else {
  echo "No\n";
}
```

Will output 'Yes'

\n \t \r The \ is just to 'escape' the character it still only takes up 1 character.

Comment: thank you, it actually was pretty much the same I was doing but now I realized it was actually receiving a \r\n instead!